# how to Order layers by name in after effects

Tags: after-effects

I have a lot of layers(100 layers) And I want to arrange them according to the name.

Answer (score 1):

To sort layers by name, you either have to name them using a numerical prefix of some sort or use a script to do it.

Ordering by name using numbers: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131728/in-after-effects-sort-project-layers-by-name-numerical-order

Here is a script: https://github.com/ff6347/after-effects-script-snippets/blob/master/automagically-sort-layers-by-name.jsx

Answer (score 0):

The excellent and free Kinda Sorta script can do this:

http://aescripts.com/rd-kinda-sorta/

It is part of a really useful set of free scripts:

http://www.redefinery.com/ae/rd_scripts/